# ACPI error (AE-ALREADY-EXISTS) while installing Debian

Tags: usb, debian, acpi, debian-installer

When I boot up my Debian 11.2 live USB stick it gives me these errors:

```
ACPI BIOS Error(bug) : Failure creating named object[\ADBG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS

ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog
```

and after these errors Debian doesn't run.

I tested it with two different USB sticks made with Rufus.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was being printing out until I updated the BIOS (on a Gigabyte Z690 DDR4 motherboard).